# How to pass json values between React component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, frontend

I have a question about passing the json data between, I have there components PassTestData/ComA/ComB, the data is imported in PassTestData and want to pass to ComA. However, there is an error message 'TypeError: data.map is not a function'. The following are my codes.

**PassTestData**

```
Import data from ‘../data.json’
const PassTestData = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      < ComA data={data} />
    </div>
  );};
```

**ComA**

```
const ComA = props => {
  const data = props;
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardTitle>
        <EmailViewHeader />
      </CardTitle>
      <Table hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Title A
            </th>
            <th>
              Title B
            </th>
            <th>
              Title C
            </th>
            <th>
              Title D
            </th>
            <th>
              Title E
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(row => (
            <ComB
              A={row.A}
              B={row.B}
              C={row.C}
              D={row.D}
              E={row.E}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Card>
  );
};
export default ComA;
```

**ComB**

```
const ComB = props => {
  const { A, B, C, D, E } = props;
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{A}</td>
      <td>{B}</td>
      <td>{C}</td>
      <td>{D}</td>
      <td>{E}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default ComB ;
```

**data.json**

```
[
    {
      "A": "dataA",
      "B": "dataB",
      "C": "dataC",
      "D": "dataD",
      "E": "dataE"
    },
    {
      "A": "dataA_2",
      "B": "dataB_2",
      "C": "dataC_2",
      "D": "dataD_2",
      "E": "dataE_2"
    },
   ]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define like `const data = props.data;` or `const {data}= props;`

```
const ComA = props => {
  const data = props.data;
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardTitle>
        <EmailViewHeader />
      </CardTitle>
      <Table hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Title A
            </th>
            <th>
              Title B
            </th>
            <th>
              Title C
            </th>
            <th>
              Title D
            </th>
            <th>
              Title E
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(row => (
            <ComB
              A={row.A}
              B={row.B}
              C={row.C}
              D={row.D}
              E={row.E}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: @LoveCat if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, will give you later, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Convert you json to object and then pass it in props. `JSON` is a string and the `map` function is not defined in it.

```
Import data from ‘../data.json’
const PassTestData = () => {
 let _data = JSON.parse(data);  
  return (
    <div>
      < ComA date={_date} />
    </div>
  );};
```

And in component A pass the props data like this.

```
const ComA = props => {
  const data = props.data;
  return (
    ....
  );
};
export default ComA
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `const data = props;` like:

```
const { data } = props;
```

OR

```
const data = props.data;
```

`TypeError: data.map is not a function` is thrown due to `props` being an Object not an Array.

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) expects an Array.

Comment: @LoveCat Glad to help! Please accept this answer if it resolved your question. [Instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).